# CSS3: white line should not be there inside button with icon?

Tags: html, css

Here is a screen grab and you can see a white line on top of icon as **shown in red arrow?**

I've checked on Illustrator and there is no white line? The icon size is 20x wide x 15px height.

[image: align top]

The CSS3 code for the button:

```
.blue_small {
height: 40px;
width: 40px;
margin-left:16px;
margin-bottom:6px;
background-color:#003F5F;
-moz-border-radius: 50%; 
-webkit-border-radius: 50%; 
border-radius: 50%;
border: 3px solid #fff;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px rgba(64,80,85,0.8);  
box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px rgba(64,80,85,0.8);}
```

UPDATED HTML5 of the section and I've included **css/normalize.css** but it doesn't make any difference:

```
      <button class="blue_small"></button>
```

It is obviously a glitch that I don't know how to get rid of it?

SOLVED: 
with background:url(../images/index_video_small2.svg) no-repeat left 5px top 7px;

[image: align top]
<sub>(source: [kerrydeaf.com](http://www.kerrydeaf.com/line_ok.png))</sub>

Comment: Can you create a fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: If I can do jsfiddle, I wouldn't be asking here. I wish I can be more helpful. I tried to be as clear as possible with screengrab with red arrow as shown just above a white line that should not be there.

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/tjSLY/ there is no border

Comment: Try this - .blue_small img{ margin: 2px 0 0 0; } and see if the border moves down

Comment: I've added and checked jsfiddles, there is no line in jsfiddles but I can see white line on my browser?

Comment: Try including normalize css in your HTML - http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/

Comment: Can you link your image?

Comment: I couldnt find any line. Check this demo http://jsfiddle.net/YP5Vd/

Comment: I agree there is nothing  on jsfiddles. But it is showing A WHITE LINE. I've updated the HTML of the section.

Comment: Even there its the same http://jsfiddle.net/YP5Vd/1/

Comment: @ Sowmya and Dipaks. I've changed my approach and make this as 'background:url(../images/arrow_cyan.svg) no-repeat left 10px;' It seem to work. Thank you